# Cross-domain AJAX requests

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I know Stackoverflow is full of this question, but...

**How to make cross-domain AJAX request?**

I do not want to use

- Proxy server
- Access-Control-Allow-Origin doesn't work
- jQuery.getJSON()
- jQuery.load()
- jQuery.get()

because, I also need to send headers

```
X-API-Version = DEV
```

Thanks for reply!

Comment: Using a proxy does not exclude setting custom HTTP headers.

Comment: What do you mean by "Access-Control-Allow-Origin doesn't work"?

Comment: I am calling from localhost and server 127.0.0.1 is responding with Access-Control-Allow-Origin = *.

Comment: It sounds like your real question is "How do I get Access-Control-Allow-Origin to work?" I suggest you ask that question with more details of what you've tried.

Comment: It sounds like you want sub-domain XMLHttpRequest. Have you looked at http://fettig.net/weblog/2005/11/30/xmlhttprequest-subdomain-update/ ?

Answer (score 8):

You can't do this, not if you exclude the methods above.  Cross-domain requests (if you want to see content) can only be made with JSONP or a proxy server...and you can't set headers with JSONP.

Comment: Even if I'm sending AJAX request to subdomain?

Comment: So how does Twitter work? It sends requests to subdomain with custom headers.

Comment: @Ryan - show me an example of this? the request is likely not behaving like you think

Comment: @Nick Thanks for reply, examples are at http://img195.imageshack.us/i/screenshot20101124at231.png/, http://img153.imageshack.us/i/screenshot20101124at231.png/.

Comment: @Ryan - both of those examples aren't cross-domain, if you see the referrer those are requests made to the same domain (`www.facebook.com` -> `www.facebook.com` and `api.twitter.com/p_receiver.html` -> `api.twitter.com/1/users...`), and are XmlHttpRequests, not JSONP.

Comment: Please, go to Twitter.com and try to open Developer Tools - Console.

Comment: @Ryan - Those requests are made from `http://api.twitter.com/p_receiver.html`...there's no cross-domain request being made there.  Take a look at your own screenshots, see the referrer?